# CKEditor is freezing when I try to build a simple widget

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am following the tutorial here, using version 4.7.3:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1

At first I was using the standard package, and I installed the widget plugin manually, adding it's dependencies as well, but not the dependencies of the dependencies because I had assumed they were included already in CKEditor.

When it froze, I started to wonder if I messed up downloading the plugin, so I downloaded a custom build, starting with the standard package and including the widget plugin. This should supposedly take care of dependencies for me.

So I began to follow the tutorial.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p id="paragraph" contentEditable>This is the body of the article.</p>
    <script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

My index.js

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

CKEDITOR.inline("paragraph",{
    extraPlugins:'simplebox'
});
```

And here is the plugin code at `ckeditor/plugins/simplebox/plugin.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'simplebox', {
    requires: 'widget',

    icons: 'simplebox',

    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'simplebox', {
            button: 'Create a simple box',
            template:"<h1>What's going on</h1>"
        } );
    }
} );
```

When I activate the editor, the icon successfully appears in the toolbar, but when I press it, the browser just freezes. Where is my error?

Here is a link to my work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/thw4yxt23jlzq49/ckeditor-widget.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You are in the middle of this tutorial so solution which you try to implement inside editor is not complete. There should be add at least `upcast` method which will define what are condition for element to became a widget. It seems to be main reason why your example is not working well.
You can check how looks entire tutorial solved here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs-samples/blob/master/tutorial-simplebox-1/simplebox/plugin.js

It might be helpful to also check widget description from documentation: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget. Usually in method documentation you can find some simple examples of its usage.